# How to add multiple "dom" option into datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a script

```
oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable({
        "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',  //  Col. visibility, provides a dropdown to hide col.s
        "dom": 'Rlfrtip',           //  For column reorder
        "columns":aColumns,
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip', // TableTool to give csv download option
        "responsive" : true,
        "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": [
                            {
                            "sExtends": "csv",
                            "sButtonText": "CSV",
                            }
                            ]
                        }
    });
```

My query is regarding how to enable this three facilites together?

```
        "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',  //  Col. visibility, provides a dropdown to hide col.s
        "dom": 'Rlfrtip',           //  For column reorder
        "columns":aColumns,
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip', // TableTool to give csv download option
```

When i am disabling any two of the three options, then the enabled options is working fine.
But i can't make all the three enabled together. May be there is some trick, but i am unable to do that.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Each option can be specified multiple times - [https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

Comment: As far i know you can use `DOM` multiple times . make it in one piece

Comment: @Saswat have you got the solution